# Gridlayout going outside of screen instead of occupying imageview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I have this layout where a gridlayout has to be on top of an imageview. I have measured everyting so that it would fit (regarding column and row count and column and row span).

Unfortunately, the grid layout goes outside the screen, instead of filling the imageview only. Any suggestions?

The xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/wood"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.luanca.charangomaster.ChordActivity"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chordin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/dark_plank"
        android:text="@string/choose_root"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chordin2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/dark_plank"
        android:text="@string/choose_type"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tip1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/help" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/chord_box1" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:columnCount="14"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="60" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="8"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fretposition1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="8"
            android:text="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fretposition2"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="8"
            android:text="2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fretposition3"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="8"
            android:text="3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fretposition4"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="8"
            android:text="4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fretposition5"
            android:layout_column="10"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="8"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty2"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_column="12"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="8"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty3"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret10"
            android:background="@drawable/no_press1"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret11"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret12"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret13"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret14"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret15"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="10"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty4"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_column="12"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty5"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="18"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret20"
            android:background="@drawable/no_press1"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="18"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret21"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="18"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret22"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="18"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret23"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="18"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret24"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="18"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret25"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="10"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="18"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty6"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_column="12"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="18"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty7"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="28"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret30"
            android:background="@drawable/no_press1"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="28"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret31"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="28"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret32"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="28"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret33"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="28"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret34"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="28"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret35"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="10"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="28"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty8"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_column="12"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="28"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty9"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="38"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret40"
            android:background="@drawable/no_press1"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="38"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret41"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="38"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret42"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="38"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret43"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="38"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret44"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="38"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret45"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="10"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="38"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty10"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_column="12"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="38"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty11"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="48"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret50"
            android:background="@drawable/no_press1"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_row="48"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret51"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="48"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret52"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="48"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret53"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="48"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret54"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="48"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fret55"
            android:background="@drawable/finger1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_column="10"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="48"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty12"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_column="12"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="48"
            android:layout_rowSpan="10" />
    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: If it isn't clear, I want it to always occupy the same space as the imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Replace your GridLayout code with this one, you are able to see views on top of your ImageView

```
   <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:columnCount="70"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="60" >
```

Hope this is what you want...

Comment: There are too many views and buttons in your xml under GridLayout therefore you need to implement horizontal scroll view in order to view remaining views.

Comment: Hmmm... but what if I want them all to appear in the screen at once?